# Shortcut for email to a specific person

Tags: email, home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts

I am new to Android, and would like to know whether it is possible to add a desktop shortcut so that when I press it, I can send an email to a specific person, and I just need to put the subject and send it.

Comment: It does seem weird this is lacking, as every phone/ROM I've had has had `Direct Call` and `Direct [Text] Message` shortcuts, so yeah, where's `Direct Email`?

Answer (score 4):

Not for a specific person -- but still a shortcut, which simply opens the "compose new mail" screen: [Compose Mail Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.austrianapps.android.compose). There's also [Send Mail Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.twnmj.android.SendMailTo) which, from the name, sounds to exactly fit your purpose -- but as it helds no description at all, it's hard to tell. Last but not least: [Mail Linker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.lamda.maillinker) even seems to fit right from its description.

Unfortunately, as already mentioned, there's no such thing provided by the Android core system by default.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's anything built in to do that, but an app like [Mail Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sak.mailwidget) will allow that.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this, the [Email Yourself](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dzogchenltd.emailyourself) app does this. Contrary to what the name suggests, you can also use it to create shortcuts to send emails to other people or groups of people.

Comment: Thanks. It's not free, but €1,09 is as good as free, and it works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

From [this discussion](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/16897-direct-email-shortcut.html) I found that [Speed Dial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.android.speeddial&hl=en) application can do the trick.

Comment: I think Speed Dial only works for smses and calls, but I could be mistaken. I tried that one a long time ago, but it can of course be updated in meantime.

Answer (score 0):

The "Contact" widget allows you to add a shortcut to a specific contact on your Home Screen.  Once you visualize the contact, you just have to click on his/her email address to send the email.

This is not exactly what you asked as it requires an additional step, however it's a feature available on all Android versions without requiring installing any external app.